# Проблема подключения Android Studio к BitBucket

Tags: android-studio, bitbucket

Здравствуйте!
С недавнего времени плагин синхронизации с 'BitBucket' перестал работать.

> Plugin Error. Problems found loading plugins: Following plugins are
> incompatible with current IDE build: Bitbucket
>
> current IDE: Android Studio 2.1.2

Поделитесь, кто как решает эту проблему. Спасибо!

Answer (score 1):

1. Скачайте плагин https://bitbucket.org/dmitry_cherkas/jetbrains-bitbucket-connector/downloads/jetbrains-bitbucket-connector_IC-139.224.zip
2. После `File > Settings > Plugins > Install plugin from disk > ФАШ_ФАЙЛ`
3. Перезапустите студию

Comment: увы, не помогло. (

Comment: Попробуйте провести эксперимент с другими версиями плагинов https://bitbucket.org/dmitry_cherkas/jetbrains-bitbucket-connector/downloads

Comment: К примеру https://bitbucket.org/dmitry_cherkas/jetbrains-bitbucket-connector/downloads/jetbrains-bitbucket-connector_IC-133.193.zip

Comment: Спасибо за подсказки, попробую. пока решил использовать SourceTree

Comment: Не за что. Удачи