# Ошибка подключения к репозиторию BitBucket

Tags: java, android, bitbucket

Подскажите кто-нибудь пожалуйста. Хотел синхронизировать проект с BitBucket, все раньше работало без проблем, но вот сегодня при попытке зайти и залить на репозиторий проект, высветился прогрессбар. И этот прогресс длиться около 5 минут, и затем выводится что ошибка подключения к BitBucket. Так в чем же проблема?
[image: Прогресс]

Comment: 1) Прежде чем задать вопрос, нужно искать похожие проблемы и ответы на них. Если отсутствуют, то задать
2) Скриншот Прогресс Бара не о чем не говорит. Впредь выкладывайте стэк-трейс, сообщение об ошибке

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Нашел статью -> [Проблема подключения Android Studio к BitBucket](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/549432/%d0%9f%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b1%d0%bb%d0%b5%d0%bc%d0%b0-%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%ba%d0%bb%d1%8e%d1%87%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%8f-android-studio-%d0%ba-bitbucket?rq=1)

Мне помогло большое спасибо https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/195819/chubatiy